# LinkedIn People API's Picture Url throws error code 500

Tags: linkedin-api

Some of the LinkedIn profile's picture url not loaded (It throws 500 error code) which urls I get it from LinkedIn likes api .

Error Description: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

Attached error page here:

```html
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat</h3></body></html>
```

Comment: I'm getting this too. Seems intermittent.

Comment: I'm getting the same error too! very weird!

Comment: I am also getting the same error. It's weird that some of the URLs work, some don't and some work if I reload a couple of times.